# Linearly independent subsets over extension of scalars

Tags: ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field, $D_{1},D_{2}$ division rings containing $k$ and $V$ a $k$-vector space of finite dimension and assume also that $V$ is a $D_{1}-D_{2}$ bimodule. Suppose $W$ is a $k$ basis of $D_{1} \otimes_{k} V$. Note that $D_{1} \otimes_{k} V \otimes_{k} D_{2}$ has structure of right $D_{2}$-module.

Is it always true that that the set $\{w \otimes 1: w \in W\}$ is a $D_{2}$-linearly independent set in $D_{1} \otimes_{k} V \otimes D_{2}$?

I think yes: assume that $\displaystyle \sum (x_{j} \otimes 1)d_{j}=0$ where $x_{j} \in W$ and $d_{j} \in D_{2}$. To show $D_{2}$-linear independence we need to verify that $d_{j}=0$ for every $j$. The above sum implies that $\displaystyle \sum x_{j} \otimes d_{j} =0$. The multiplication map $D_{1} \otimes_{k} V \otimes_{k} D_{2} \rightarrow V$ implies that $\displaystyle \sum x_{j}d_{j}=0$. Now for each $x_{j}$ in the basis $W$ consider the dual basis element $x_{j}^{\ast}$ so applying this to the sum we conclude that $d_{j}=0$ for each $j$ so we have linear independence in $D_{2}$.

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $B$ is an $R$-basis of some right $R$-module $M$, then for every $R \to S$ the set $\{b \otimes 1 : b \in B\}$ is an $S$-basis of $M \otimes_R S$. This is because $- \otimes_R S$ commutes with direct sums and maps $R$ to $S$, hence $\oplus_B R \otimes_R S \cong \oplus_B S$.

Comment: thanks; that helps. Just being curious: is the "proof" correct?